# Different ways to define props in React.FunctionalComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Are there any significant differences between those two ways to define props in `React.FunctionalComponent`?

```js
interface Props {
    username: string,
    age: number
}

const UserPanel: React.FunctionComponent = (props: Props) => (
    <div>{props.username}</div>
);

const UserPanel: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => (
    <div>{props.age}</div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a quite significant difference: Option one is throwing away type information.

The function on the right hand side includes information about the props, but then you assign it to a variable that does not have that information. `UserPanel`'s type uses the default props of `{}` so whoever uses UserPanel can not pass in any props. Attempting to pass in a username prop or age prop will throw an error. For example:

```
const UserPanel: React.FunctionComponent = (props: Props) => (
    <div>{props.username}</div>
);

const SomeOtherCmponent = () => {
  // Error: Type '{ username: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  return <UserPanel username="foo" age={100}/>
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUI8AHYxZQF5ZwAKxYdAG9GcMXACuqDi2QgsALjioYUVgHMANKPHJ1iuCwkgARh0YBfRo1wQWKuAFVpUXshZYANkux4YAOgAxCRZ8YDsAYRJIDzY4AF44AAowAVQlfghBAEoEgD5knTEAHgATYAA3PKFUrNR-KRk5LAtigHpyqsZs+iYGW3t4AGUSLAB5GAALDgjwOyw4xKTc+IKRBjFKGAkoFjhi5w43D09JF1l5eIAiAggIK5R9eKEARgAGN4s2vOsGCyA)

You either need to do your second option:

```
const UserPanel: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => (
    <div>{props.age}</div>
);
```

Or you need to do this:

```
const UserPanel = (props: Props) => (
    <div>{props.age}</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first ways to define props in `React.functionComponent` will emit an error:

```
Type '(props: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': username, agets(2322)
```

If we look into the type definition of `React.FunctionComponent` (in my case React v18.2.45) we'll see:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P, context?: any): ReactNode;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

Basically, the error tells us that the definition of the `props` in `React.FunctionComponent` `{}` does not match the definition of `interface Props { name: string, age: number }` which you passed in.

Let's explain the type definition of `props` in `React.FunctionComponent`.

- `P = {}` : This is a generic parameter. It represents the props that the function component expects. By default, it's an empty object, meaning no props are expected.
- `(props: P, context?: any): ReactNode`: This is the function signature for the component. It takes two parameters: props and context. props is of type `P` (the props the component expects), and context is optional and can be of any type. The function returns a ReactNode, which can be any valid React child (a React element, string, number, etc.).

Because in `React.FunctionComponent`, `props` is expecting the generic type `P` (which is `{}`), you have to define the generic type `P` inorder to pass into `UserPanel` component. This is where your second way to define props in `React.FunctionComponent` comes in.

```
const UserPanel: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => (
    <div>{props.age}</div>
);
```